# DPM2010 / Windows 2012 - DCOM errors communicating with all agents

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, backup, windows-server-2012, scdpm

I just installed DPM 2010 on a Windows 2012 machine. Everything appears fine but then I try attaching an agent and the server can never communicate with any agent.

I tried installing/uninstalling agents from the server and it times out. I tried manually installing the agent on the client machine and the server still can't communicate with it. I tried installing agents on machines with Windows 2003R2/2008R2/2012R2 and all have same results.

Here are the errors I'm getting on the server:

> DCOM got error "2147942405" from the computer server.example.com when
>   attempting to activate the server:
>   {DA6AA17A-D61C-4E9C-8CEA-DB25DEA52A95}

I never had this issue in the past, but I always had DPM2010 installed on Windows 2008 R2. Could this be a DCOM security feature with Windows 2012?

Comment: bump...not a single comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to get on the DPM server, unjoin domain, delete computer object from AD, rejoin domain on DPM server, add new DPM server object to "Distributed COM Users" AD group.

Next, follow directions to install the agents manually: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb870935.aspx

Do not skip the step about running SetDPMServer.exe!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error message with DPM 2016. The cause - I had removed `NT Authority\Authenticated Users` from the local `Users` group on the protected server.

I added the `DOMAIN\DpmServerName` account as a member for the local `Users` group and the error went away.